# Libraries Importing

Tags: python, numpy

Try to Import libraries but gives an Error.

```
!pip install opencv-contrib-python

Collecting opencv-contrib-python Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/a3/dfdbd5db6ba7f5b5a34d969c7508866c48826c61eb5e2c913d27f8784ff4/opencv_contrib_python-4.1.1.26-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.15.4)
Installing collected packages: opencv-contrib-python

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\cv2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Guide me to this.

Comment: As it says, you don't have permissions to that path. (NOTE: This isn't a code-related problem.)

Comment: If you are a Windows user, try `runas /noprofile /user:Administrator !pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to install to the `admin` folder, you will need to open a prompt with administrative privileges. Also, I recommend using the `conda` package manager if you are using Anaconda.